# How to call a Kotlin top-level function as Apache Camel expression

Tags: kotlin, apache-camel, spring-camel

I am using Apache Camel in my Spring/Kotlin application. Camel let's you call a method on a bean; for example:

```kotlin
.transform(body().method("MyBean", "myMethod"))
```

How can I call a Kotlin top-level function or extension function instead, where there is no bean that has been registered with Camel beforehand? I am looking for something like `.method("myFunction")`.